# How to construct a menu with a drill down table pointing to other ViewControllers in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, drilldown

I'm new to Objective-C, I like it,
I'm developping a free application for the local firefighters.
The app does nothing really hard, but I have a big problem with the main menu:
I have already created a table content all the section of my application, I am trying to implement the drill down method by means I can access to other ViewControllers, but I really don't know how to do it, I googled a lot but I've only found fragmentary documentation referenced to old versions of Xcode.
I'm using version 4.5.2 and the storyboard.

[image]

Here is the menu.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface Menu : UITableViewController
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *listaMenu; //questo sarà il mio array contentente le varie opzioni della tabella

    @end
```

And the menu.m

```
#import "Menu.h"
#import "News.h"

@interface Menu ()

@end

@implementation Menu

@synthesize listaMenu; //creo i metodi getter e setter

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Menu";

    //Elementi da visualizzare nella tabella
    listaMenu = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"News", @"Memebri", @"Calendario", @"Interventi", @"Galleria", @"Mezzi", @"Reclutamento",  nil];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //funzione in cui va inserito il numero di righe da visualizzare

    return [listaMenu count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlistCell"];

    if(cell == nil){

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"PlistCell"];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [listaMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath //Rende gli oggetti NON editabili
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    //return YES;
    return NO;

}




#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}

@end
```

I hope my problem is well explained.

**Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up about `UISegue` - this is the object that handles transitions from one `UIViewController` to another controller.  In Interface Builder you can Ctrl-Drag to create a Segue between, say a `UIButton` and the desired `UIViewController`.  This is the simplest usage of segues.

If you need to pass data to the destination UIViewController then you'll need to implement the `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method.  Within this method you can get the `segue.destinationViewController` and then send it whatever data you need.  N.B. The destination view controller's view has not loaded yet, so if you're trying to customise `UIView`s directly, then they won't exist.  You can fudge it by doing `[segue.destinationViewController view]` to get going, although it would be better to configure non-UI properties and have the view controller itself do any necessary customisation in `viewDidLoad`.